# Codeigniter not finding file url helper

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have this setup:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>artistas/index" class="menu-link effect link">ARTISTAS</a>
```

But when I click on that link, it takes me to http://localhost/Universal%20Music/Universal/artistas/index which says 404, like if there's nothing there but I've already created the controller with that name loading some views in it. Am I missing something here?

**EDIT**

My config.php has:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Universal/Universal';
```

I stop using spaces in the names of the folders and now the path is:
*C:\Users\Horacio\Documents\Projects\Universal\Universal*

The controller file has the same name of the class I need and the code inside is:

```
<?php
class Artistas extends CI_Controller {

   function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
   }


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('main-index');
    }
}
```

Comment: Make your folder without spaces i.e. universalmusic and change that in `APPPATH . config/config.php` as `$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/universalmusic/";`

Comment: Thanks, but it's still showing 404. I tried with a basic configuration, creating a test folder and loading the default controller but editing the default welcome_message view with just an anchor in it which linked to a test controller but it's still 404. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Is root of your application in Universal folder? Is helper loaded? What is set as `base_url`? Is name of class same as name of controller file? What version is used regarding capital and lower letter? Can you post controller code? :)

Comment: We need more info. @Tpojka has the right ideas. What does your `config.php` look like?

Comment: Thanks guys, I just added some edits to the post with the info you needed to debug, hope it helps. I even checked a youtube tutorial just in case I was missing something, following the exact same steps but they seem not to be working. I think there must be something in my pc that's not leting codeigniter load or find the controller? even though it's a 404 so it's not something permission related.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, the config.php file mentions that the base_url should have a trailing slash eg `http://example.com/`, maybe this is an issue?

Comment: Nah. I removed that just in case too but it's just comments I guess. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: If you are using WAMP (or something similar) then another issue might be your `.htaccess` file.  I'm just trying to think of the possibilities. `.htaccess` files can affect your whole localhost if you're not careful.